# What is the appropriate approach to disable web page caching in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to disable web files caching for 1 tab in Chrome. is there a way to do so? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Press Shift+Refresh to reload the page anew or hold shift and click the refresh button.

If you are authoring the webpage, then @VettelS would be right - or you could use the HTTP header when sending/receiving pages. Chrome just sends the Cache-Control: no-cache header when you press Shift + Refresh.

Though all of the above is my own not-really research; don't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I've made a Chrome extension that **disables browser cache for specific websites**, just what you need.

Take a look – it's called [Cache Disabler](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension). Here's how it appears in action:

[image: Screenshot of “Cache Disabler” Chrome extension]

With it, you can **see your changes immediately** without relying on the hit-and-miss Ctrl+refresh.

There's no shortage of Chrome extensions that disable cache. However, what sets [Cache Disabler](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension) apart is its ability to **persist and sync your settings after a browser restart**. As far as I know, no other extension offers that, which is always appreciated when developing websites.

[It's open-source](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension), any feedback is welcome!